# Java Encoding string not converting properly

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a couple of string that aren't converting properly. The issue that I had was that all my strings had weird characters on it (They are in spanish with the top accent) and I was able to convert them with the following code:

Connection to DB:
After is connected I proceed to get the information from the DB as follows (it comes with json format) DB information shows as PerÃƒÂº:

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    //is.close();
    Log.i("Tag:", result);
}
```

retrieve JSON list:

```
try{
    jArray = new JSONArray(welcome.result);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("log_tag", "title:" + json_data.getString("title"));

        try {
            country = new String(json_data.getString("country").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){

        }
```

However I grabbed another string in spanish and it reverted back but the other strings still show up properly. The current string looks like this PER�?º
Any ideas? Im guessing is using a different encoding. The database where I'm pulling them from uses utf8_general_ci. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If `json_data` is a `String` retrieved from the database using `getString()` on a `ResultSet`, and you're getting `PER�?º`, then whoever inserted that data messed up.

Comment: @Andreas but in the DB the information shows as PerÃƒÂº

Comment: you should indeed try to query your DB with MySQLWorkbench (assuming that you use MySQL) to see what you have in your table, It may not have been loaded properly as suggested by @Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
country = json_data.getString("country");
```

`getString` returns already a `String` so no need to encode it into `ISO-8859-1` to decode it into `UTF-8` which cannot work for obvious reasons.

If you get incorrect characters even with the code above, it means that your problem comes before, probably while parsing your `JSON` content, it has probably not been parsed with the correct character encoding.

You need to explicitly set the character encoding to `UTF-8` otherwise it will use the default one as next:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was doing this at the beginning but the characters were coming weird and thats when I added the encoding

Comment: so even with this, you don't have correct characters?

Comment: unfortunately half of the list looks ok but the other half is still coming in with this weird characters, im guessing they are in a different encoding from ISO-8859-1

Comment: if so it means that your problem comes before while parsing your Json data,  it has probably not been parsed with the correct encoding, your problem is not here for sure

Comment: hmm im pulling the characters from my db and I stored them here with utf 8, then when they come in it looks liek this PerÃƒÂº and then after my code it looks like this PER�?º

Comment: @NicolasFilotto See [my answer/rambling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37633367/5221149) to maybe get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you for all your help! I looked at my DB code to solve this issue and it works! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make sense of what you show.

You say database shows `PerÃƒÂº`.

In [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), that is the bytes `50 65 72 C3 83 C2 BA`.

Those bytes as UTF-8 is `PerÃº`.

In [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), that is the bytes `50 65 72 C3 BA`.

Those bytes as UTF-8 is `Perú`.  **<== Right value**

It would seem you have a double bad encoding going on here.

One bad encoding could be from "database shows", i.e. how do you see what database shows?

Other bad encoding is that whoever inserted the data messed up.

I would postulate that database actually has `PerÃº` stored in UTF-8. The tools you use to show the value is doing it wrong. Of course, whoever inserted the value was doing it wrong too, hence the double error.

*Solution:* You start by fixing the code that inserted bad data. You also use a tool that can correctly show what's in the database.

Then you remove any encoding hacks from your Java code, because it very likely is doing it right to being with. Or at least, it's not the Java to database part of the code that is bad.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for all your help! If I could choose two responses that helped me solve my issue I would select yours as well! I looked at my db and solve the issue there!